# Android WebView opens uTorrent app when links are clicked

Tags: java, android, webview

I made an app for Google Play and it uses the webview component to function, and somebody contacted me about an issue that I have. He said that whenever he clicks on a link inside the app it opens the uTorrent app, I even tried this myself and it is a very annoying issue.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem of uTorrent comflicting with WebView?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing text to a browser (i.e. a URL/URI) that starts with `magnet:?`? Because that would cause that behaviour.

Comment: I am just linking to a page in the application assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

this will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never would of found that out by myself.

Comment: @user1563185 your welcome, but there is a small problem. I use this method and when i call javascript:history.back() from android it goes back and forward in two last page. If I find a solution I will share it with you.